# Do I have to assign permissions to groups used for audiencing?

Tags: audience-targeting, audiences

My understanding is that the Audience function allows you to specify a group name and that SharePoint will then selectively show the link in the Quick Launch Nav area depending on the users membership in the group.

My question is, if I am using the group container solely for audiences, does it need to have permissions set, or can it simply be a group container to hold user names?

I am using MOSS 2007

Answer (score 1):

At least for SP 2007 you should not have to give permissions to a group that you only are using for audiencing